# Websocket on Java SE?

Tags: java, websocket

I want to make real time chat and I want to use Java SE with `websockets` on server side and html/JS on client side. It's very hard to find `websocket` library that works with Java SE (or I'm looking at wrong places). Is using Java SE for `websocket` application at all good solution?

I followed this tutorial:
https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/
but imports are not working well for me:

```
The import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure cannot be resolved
```

Is this because Java EE is required?

Please give mu URL of some (working) tutorial/youtube video. I'm using Eclipse and I'm not too experienced with it, so "for dummies" rated article will be more suitable.

I know that question is not very precise, but I'm desperate - wasted days, tried few different libraries, but nothing works, so I just need to get it running.

Comment: Hi. I found this link: http://architects.dzone.com/articles/sample-java-web-socket-client.

Comment: also see this link : http://www.hascode.com/2014/11/creating-different-websocket-chat-clients-in-java/#Chat_Server

Comment: At end I moved to NetBeans, and Java EE and this example worked at first try: blog.idrsolutions.com/2013/12/websockets-an-introduction

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[Jetty](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty) is a very lightweight library that helps JavaSE developer with all kind of network communication for client and server. Chat applications have been the 'hello world' for such a kind of library. I would recommand any good tutorial on this (just type websocket chat jetty in your favorite browser). If your main goal is to LEARN how it works, instead of copy/paste, I would recommand a simpler tutorial [like this one.](http://jansipke.nl/websocket-tutorial-with-java-server-jetty-and-javascript-client/)

Comment: ??? Reason for downvote ??? My answer is a perfect valid answer. I use jetty embedded in my application every day with great success.

Comment: Agreed.  Jetty is a good solution to not having to write all the ancillary web handling things manually.  I also use an embedded jetty server in an SE application.  <upvote>

Comment: Java SE does not contain the websocket implementation. Jetty is one of the most known and easy to use library for this purpose. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: @TrapII I've had to learn to let go of downvotes, especially since they can be given anonymously without justification - they end up having very little impact on your rep (They cause more mental aggrivation than anything). You see now half a year later you have two upvotes (I gave you one). Thanks for the answer.